# Is there a function to save the number of checked checkboxes in a variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a wpf app with 20 Checkboxes.
Is there a function to Safe the number of the checkboxes which are checked in a variable. 
If there is an other possibility to use the number without saving it in a variable first, that would help me too.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi -- welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be useful for you to show us what you have tried, by posting some code in your question. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in, but a loop or Linq query shouldn't be too hard. If you want all checkboxes on the form, you could just do

```
int count = 0;

for (var control in parent.Children)
{
    if (control is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)control).IsChecked)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

or

```
int count = parent.Children.OfType<CheckBox>()
                           .Where(cb => cb.IsChecked)
                           .Count();
```

If you have move specific conditions (e.f. checkboxes that have a specific name pattern), then just add that to the `if` or `Where` clause.